# Laravel - Timestamp field being read as string

Tags: php, laravel, timestamp

I have a custom timestamp field in my database, `delivery_date`

```
$table->timestamp('delivery_date')->nullable();
```

Whenever I try to utilize this field, it brings it in as a string...

```
"2018-12-17 00:00:00"
```

but if I use the same code with the `created_at` timestamp for example, it brings it in as the timestamp.

`date: 2018-12-09 00:00:00.0 America/New_York (-05:00)`

I have attempted changing the field in the migration to `datetime` and `date` with the same result.

I have also attempted converting the result via...

```
strtotime($order->delivery_date)
```

but for some reason it converts it to an integer.

Comment: _"but for some reason it converts it to an integer"_ - the reason is, that [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) returns a timestamp, which is an integer (seconds since 1970)

Comment: both your returns (the first "non working" and the second "working" _are strings_, just in a slightly different format. How do you check the type of the return?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

in order to get delivery_date as created_at you have to add delivery_date to your model as `protected $dates = ['delivery_date'];`